# error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘boost::filesystem::path::filename() const() + "/"’

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm working with this source but I get this error:

```
  In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:15:0,
[LIST=1]
                 from luascript.cpp:21:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp:16:5: error: #error Compiling Filesystem version 3 file with BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION defined != 3
luascript.cpp: In member function ‘bool LuaInterface::loadDirectory(const string&, Npc*, bool)’:
luascript.cpp:745:61: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘boost::filesystem::path::filename() const() + "/"’
make[1]: *** [luascript.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dv/src.DEB'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[/LIST]
```

With this section of code:

```
if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(it->status()))
        {
            if(recursively && !loadDirectory(it->path().filename() + "/" + s, npc, recursively))
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
if(recursively && !loadDirectory(it->path() / s, npc, recursively))
            return false;
```

It's shorter, more elegant, optimized for allocations **and** platform-independent!

IMO this one the rarer cases where non-traditional operator overloading works *really* well to achieve "instant" intuitive eDSL in C++ :)

Comment: @user3084450 to convert to a string, use one of the documented path accessors: `native()`, `generic_string()` etc. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers